Was the Atari 800 expansion port hidden because of RF emission?
I just stumbled on a curious detail about the Atari 8-bit machines that I had not known about: https://forums.atariage.com/topic/133652-400800-expansion-port-pinouts/

I've seen questions about the hidden expansion ports on the 400/800 machines, however I've never seen any real answers. Both machines have aft card edge connectors, but you wouldn't know it, unless you've disassembled one, since there is no removable plastic hatch plate.


Apparently, these connectors were used for quality control testing, after the components were assembled, and before the cases were put on in the factory, to make sure that the machines were working correctly.

Other personal computers in similar form factor always had at least one general expansion port of the 'exposed edge connector' kind at the back of the machine, but then, Atari was the only personal computer manufacturer that complied with the 1970s version of FCC regulations on RF emission; all the others either used a dodge, or waited until the regulations changed in the 80s.
I'm guessing this is not a coincidence, and the Atari 800 edge connector is hidden, because exposing it in the machine as sold, would have made it impossible to keep RF emissions below the 70s limit. Is that correct?

The question is very different, but I think the answer addresses this too. (And the question has a photo of the hidden expansion port!)

@StephenKitt Oh yes, the discussion around that question does indeed provide supporting evidence that this was the reason.
